# Trying to switch tomcat to undertow, getting No "ServletContext set" error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, undertow

I'm using `spring-boot-starter-web` package which includes Tomcat as a default implementation of a servlet.

As far as I know I need to exclude `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` and enable `spring-boot-starter-undertow` to make it work. (Have to say that with Tomcat application is working fine)
However, I faced that kind of error when I tried to run it with these changes:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' defined in class path resource [config/SwaggerConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [config/SwaggerConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' defined in class path resource [config/SwaggerConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [config/SwaggerConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [config/SwaggerConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
```

SwaggerConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))
                .paths(regex("/.*"))
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

I have debugged it and found out that inside `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping()` I really do have initialized ServletContext if it's a Tomcat, but when I have an Undertow that variable is a null.
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.resourceHandlerMapping()

There it's not a null
[image]

Here it is a null
[image]

If you need an additional info please let me know

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Suffering issues moving from tomcat to undertow myself